# Ratio of images changed after update

Tags: magento2, layout, upgrade, image

After updating from Magento 2.3.5 to Magento 2.4.5-p1,
I noticed that the aspect ratio of 1 image of 1 specific productpage has been changed.
The rendered size, rendered aspect ratio, intrinsic size and the intrinsic aspect ratio have been changed, compared to before update.

I understand that this can have something to do with the view.xml of the theme.

After examination, I dont see any differences with how this was before upgrading Magento.

Could someone maybe point me in a direction to better understanding why the aspect ratio of images can change after performing an update of Magento?
For example, files to examine, or maybe a useful URL with more information.

Answer (score 1):

- It's worth noting that the image aspect ratio could also be affected by the image file itself.
- For example, if the image was resized before the upgrade, it could have been stretched or distorted, which would affect the aspect ratio.
- You can try to compare the original image with the current image to see if there are any differences.